# Mongo working with Django max_length issue for CharField

Tags: django, mongodb

I'm having problems with getting Django to work with MongoDB. So when I work in a Django shell I get no errors and can query and add things to my database.

The problem comes when I run 'python manage.py runserver'. When I do this, I get the following errors:

patientapp.patient: "first_name": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.

This is strange because in this tutorial, they don't give CharField a max length:

http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your model definition?

Comment: different behaviors of shell and devserver? sounds like misconfiguration of env or different module loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `runserver` invokes schema validation and `shell` doesn't, and a `CharField` without `max_length` isn't a valid in a Django schema.  Looks like a bug in the tutorial, patches welcome.